# Window Procedure within class

Tags: c++, user-interface, window, return, procedure

I'm wondering why the window-procedure within a class is only working if I return the non-static window procedure. So, why do I have to return the window procedure for manipulating the current window - why is a function-call not enough?

I used the example from here: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17894/Simple-Mapping-of-WndProc-to-your-Specific-Class-W

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Win::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {    
// Recover the pointer to our class, don't forget to type cast it back

CWin* winptr = (CWin*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
// Check if the pointer is NULL and call the Default WndProc

if (winptr == NULL) {
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
} else {
    // Call the Message Handler for my class (MsgProc in my case)

    return winptr->MsgProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam); // <-- 
}
```

The member function which is being called looks like this:

```
switch (msg) {
case WM_NCPAINT:
    break;
    ...
}
```

Actually the current window should be only white. Without any title bar, etc.
This works only if I return the function

```
return winptr->MsgProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam); // working 

winptr->MsgProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam); // has no effect
```

So, why do I have to return the function so that I can manipulate the current window?

Comment: The return value of your msgproc determines if default behavior takes place after the call. Basically the return value indicates, if you handled the message or not.

Comment: Reaching the closing brace of a non-void function without encountering a `return` statement exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I got it. :)